# How to install meteor for backend only?

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze, angular-meteor

is there a direct way to install just the meteor backend, because by default we are getting both client and server with a mini mongo in it. 
I have my client app, and I want to connect to meteor using asteroid library. So I don't want meteor to be overloaded with client folders, instead it should be with a server only.

It would be a great help if you could get back on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all packages related to the client and Remove "pre-installed" client side file directories. Add Restivus Package if you want to work on a restful API. 
You can find the packages inside .meteor/packages file.

Answer (score 3):

1. Delete the /client folder
2. Make sure there is no /lib folder
3. Make sure *all* the code is either in /server or /imports

Answer (score 2):

As i can see, we can't do this
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6091#issuecomment-175424043

My suggestion it's to put all your code into `import/server`

Answer (score 0):

You can  create your separate client side running on different port. Use this package to add all necessary package to connect meteor.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-client-side